# Fastest "for" loop

Tags: c++, performance, loops, for-loop, struct

Let's suppose we have this struct

```
struct structure
{
    type element;
    int size;
}
```

and we're in the main and we want to iterate something.

Is it faster

```
for ( int i = 0; i < structure.size; ++i )
```

or

```
int size = structure.size;
for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
```

?

Does weight more the continous binding to sctructure in the first method or the additional space of memory, and the time spent creating the first variable in the first line of method n.2?

I can't see any other difference between the two of them, so if you do, please share!

EDIT: I edited the question so that is now concise, simple and easy answerable. 
Please reconsider the vote you would give to it. Thank you.

Comment: Have you measured it?

Comment: Perfect topic for this quote: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%"

Comment: @mariozski there's a difference between personal stuff (where i happily waste a week optimizing something unimportant because it's fun), and professional stuff (where i'd get fired for doing so). Premature optimization isn't _always_ bad.

Comment: Both equal I am sure your compiler is smart enough optimize codeat low level. with GCC you can explicitly force for better optimization with flag `-o3, -o2`

Comment: The giant "PERFORMANCE" in your title is very redundant with the tag there.

Comment: @CoryNelson perfectly optimized code is very often unreadable, so premature optimization is bad most of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a good reason to choose one over the other. If the contents of your loop in the first example change the value of `structure.size`, `i` will be continuously checked against the current value. However, in your second choice, `size` will not change as `structure.size` does. Which one you want depends on the problem. I would perhaps change `size` to be called `initialSize` instead, however.

If that is not the case, you should stop thinking about such minor "optimizations" and instead think about what is most readable. I'd prefer the first choice because it doesn't introduce an unnecessary variable name. When you have two bits of code that do the same thing, trust the compiler to work out the optimal way of doing it. It's *your job* to tell the compiler what you want your program to do. It's the *compilers job* to do it in the best way it can.

If and only if you determine through *measurement* that this is a necessary optimization (I can't imagine that it ever will be) should you then choose the one that measures fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You should allow compiler to do microoptimizations like this. Write readable code, make it work, then if it runs slow profile it and optimize where it is really necessary.

Though in case inside the loop you call a function, that can modify this structure and compiler does not have access to it's implementation second variant may help, as you give compiler a hint that it does not need to reload structure.size from memory. I would recommend to use const:

```
const int size = structure.size;
for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i ) {
   somefunc( &structure );
}
```

Comment: if you say so, what my compiler will do to optimize my code? will it take it closer to the first or to the second version?

Comment: Optimization is not easy topic. Compiler can load it into register if there is available one. It can store it in temporary place like you suggested, or load it directly from structure. It has all available information for that. But anyway difference will be so small, you need real reason to optimize it yourself, other than just wonder.

Answer (score 0):

Very unlikely that there will be any actual difference in the compiled code from this, unless it's REALLY an ancient compiler with really rubbish optimisation. Anything like gcc, clang, MSVC or Intel's C++ compilers would produce exactly the same code for these scenarios.

Of course, if you start calling a function inside the condition of the loop, and the data processed by the function is modified by the loop, e.g.

```
std::string str;

cin >> str;
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
{
    if (str[i] > 'a') 
       str+= 'B';
}
```

then we have a different story...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much you know about **compilation**, but among the various **phases of a compiler**, there is a phase called **code-optimization**, which attempts to improve the intermediate code *(by performing various optimization techniques like dead-code elimination, loop transformations, etc.)*, so that faster-running machine code can be produced.

So, actually your compiler takes care of your headache and I doubt that you would notice any performance issues.

Answer (score -1):

In your first method, if *structure* is a reference or a member variable, it will not be properly stored into the CPU cache, as there is no way to tell if it is changed outise this block.

In your second method, as *size* is a local variable to the current code block, it will be properly stored in cache.

Thus, the second method should be faster, despite creating a new variable.

See [Load-Hit-Store](http://alex-simon.blogspot.be/2010/04/load-hit-store.html) for a more complete explanation.